# OpenGL active texture redefinition error with '=': function as left operand

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to build the open source project [nanogui-sdl](https://github.com/dalerank/nanogui-sdl) in Visual Studio 2015.

After adding all the necessary libraries, I get the following two errors:

```
Error C2365 - 'glActiveTexture': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
Error C2659 - '=': function as left operand
```

Here are the offending lines of code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC glActiveTexture;
#else

...

#ifdef WIN32
    ASSIGNGLFUNCTION(PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC,glActiveTexture)
#endif
```

Comment: I managed to compile this just fine on a Linux system by running `cmake`. How are you performing the build?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used cmake to create Visual Studio files and am trying to run the debug verison from within VS2015 using the v140 Platform Toolset.

Comment: did you type in anything special after cmake?